# Moving an object in the direction of the camera

Tags: c++

I'm making a project where I need to move a player in any direction using an analog stick. I'm limited to specific functions and I only have the positions of the camera and the player and the analog stick. The camera is always pointed to the player.

```
vec2 &leftStick = getLeftStick(-1); // results in an x and a y, both ranging from -1 to 1.

vec3 *playerPos = getTrans(player);
vec3 *cameraPos = getCameraPos(player, 0);

playerPos->x += leftStick.x * 10.0f;
playerPos->z -= leftStick.y * 10.0f;
```

This code works to move the player, however its using the orientation of the world. I need it where holding up on the analog stick (left stick y = 1) makes the player go forward, no matter what way the player/camera are facing.

Comment: playerpos - camerapos will give you your forward direction, cross(forward, up) will give you your left-right direction, then you just sum the x & y components. fairly certain this should work, you'll have to normalize in a few places though but thats the basic idea. and be careful for cases like when the camera looks straight down, this code wont work so you could clamp how high the camera goes to avoid that

Comment: *"makes the player go forward, no matter what way the player/camera are facing."* -- um... the "forward" of the player is very dependent on what way the player is facing.

Comment: I did something like that borgleader and got it working. Edited my post with the solution- thanks! and JaMiT, thats not relevant in my scenario.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Comment: @mario If that's not relevant, I guess I don't understand what you are asking for (i.e. "forward"). Please be more precise in your problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, thank you @Borgleader for a majority of it.

I found an equation to find the distance and velocity for the x and z online, then I tested a bunch of combinations until it worked properly. Not a good way to do this but it worked out.

```
// this all replaces the last two lines of the previous code snippet
float speed = 30.0f;
float d = sqrt(powf(playerPos->x - cameraPos->x, 2) + powf(playerPos->z - cameraPos->z, 2));
float vx = (speed/d)*(playerPos->x - cameraPos->x);
float vz = (speed/d)*(playerPos->z - cameraPos->z);

playerPos->x -= leftStick.x * vz;
playerPos->z += leftStick.x * vx;

playerPos->x += leftStick.y * vx;
playerPos->z += leftStick.y * vz;
```